# SBT import option not found: Idea Ultimate

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sbt, playframework-2.4

I just installed the **Intellij Idea 14.0** as IDE for play framework. And when I tried to import play project, I don't see option to import it as SBT project.

[image]

Have I missed anything here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to open the IDEA anyway and then install the **scala** plugin. After that I restarted the IDEA and then the option was there.